# Is there any option for extentX Server / selenium reporting tool?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, reporting, extent, selenium-extent-report

I have used extentX server in windows 7.Now I have installed windows 10 in my machine. Its not working now.It throws error . I am looking for other option for reporting.

An Open source where we can store the automated generate reports and it should connect with selenium.

suggest something if you know.